# How to inject custom function to class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, extends

I would like to inject a custom function into my class from variable `functions`, how can I do this?

My code is:

```
const functions = {
    foo: () => console.log('foo') 
}

class ParentBase {
    parentHello() {
        console.log('parentHello')
    }
}

function Base() {
    class BaseClass extends ParentBase { }
    BaseClass.foo = functions['foo']
    return BaseClass;
} 

const Class = Base();
const instance = new Class(); 

instance.parentHello() // it work
instance.foo() // foo  is not a function
```

Comment: This: `BaseClass.foo  ` should be `this.foo `. You want to access it via instance then it needs to be a part of instance. `BaseClass.` would put it on function

Comment: Why is the Base class inside a Base function?

Comment: @Rajesh `this` is the global scope.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes I later realised the mistake but added an answer to properly add properties on instances

Answer (score 3):

You could directly declare a new method in the class declaration:

```
class BaseClass extends ParentBase { 
  foo() {functions["foo"](); }
}
```

If the method name should be dynamic, you can also use computed method names:

```
class BaseClass extends ParentBase { 
  [window.location]() {functions["foo"](); }
}
```

If you really want to "dynamically inject" a new method (e.g. conditionally, in a loop, or some other strange construct), you'd have to write into `BaseClass.prototype`, which is the object BaseClass instances will inherit from:

```
BaseClass.prototype.foo = functions["foo"];
```

This will however be an enumerable property, to create a non enumerable one, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(BaseClass.prototype, "foo", {
  value: functions["foo"],
  /* enumerable: false,
     writable: false */
});
```

Here is a small showcase:

```js
class ParentBase {
    parentHello() {
        console.log('parentHello')
    }
}

function Base() {
    class BaseClass extends ParentBase {
      instanceMethod() { console.log("BaseClass.prototoype.test", this); };
      static classMethod() { console.log("BaseClass.classMethod", this); };
    }
    BaseClass.classMethod2 = function() { console.log("BaseClass.classMethod2", this); };
    BaseClass.prototype.instanceMethod2 = function() { console.log("BaseClass.prototype.instanceMethod2", this); };
    Object.defineProperty(BaseClass.prototype, "instanceMethod3", { value() { console.log("BaseClass.prototype.instanceMethod3", this); } });
    
    return BaseClass;
} 

const Class = Base();
const instance = new Class();

Class.classMethod();
Class.classMethod2();

instance.instanceMethod();
instance.instanceMethod2();
instance.instanceMethod3();
```

Comment: Ok, again, I updated my question, I would like to inject function dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2  places to access properties:

- Instance based
- Class Based

What you have is adding to class but you are trying to access using instance.

What you are trying to achieve is called Mixins. These are partial utility functions list that can be shared across multiple classes.

To inject properties to instances, you can either use constructor based approach or you can inject them to prototype

```js
class ParentBase {
  parentHello() {
    console.log('parentHello')
  }
}

const mixin = {
  foo: function() { console.log('foo') },
  bar: function() { console.log('Bar') },
  fooBar: function() { console.log('foo-bar') }
}

function Base() {
  class BaseClass extends ParentBase {}
  Object.assign(BaseClass.prototype, mixin)
  return BaseClass;
}

const Class = Base();
const instance = new Class();

instance.parentHello() // it work
instance.foo() // foo  is not a function
instance.fooBar()
```

---

You should also know that functions/ properties added on prototype are shared across instances. So its advice to have function but not variables as it will introduce side-effect